# Scroll only right section of page section on body scroll

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm making a webpage in Vuejs and I have to make a section of that page very similar [this site's landing page](https://www.wealthsimple.com/en-ca/product/cash/) (Check screenshot below).

[image]

I was able to create a similar layout but I'm facing an issue with scrolling the right `<div class="col position-relative">` of this layout when user is scrolling the scroll on body.

Here is what I did in Vuejs

```
<!--Other sections of page-->
<template>
<section ref="rainbow" class="suggestion-container section-padding">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end h-100 pull-left">
        <p class="suggestion-label">
          Create your own Stack of
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col position-relative">
        <div class="glass top"></div>
        <div v-view="'visible'" ref="stacks" style="transition: 0.3s all ease; transform: translateY(260px)">
          
          <p data-color="rgba(255, 116, 0, 0.7)" class="stack-name">Guitar</p>
          <p data-color="rgba(255, 170, 0, 0.7)" class="stack-name">Gaming Laptop</p>
          <p data-color="rgba(128, 42, 219, 0.7)" class="stack-name">Euro trip</p>
          <p data-color="rgba(255, 79, 123, 0.7)" class="stack-name">Phone for Dad</p>
         
        </div>
        <div class="glass bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Other sections of page-->
</template>

<script>
// Necessary imports
export default {
  mounted() {
    ...
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll(e) {
      if (!this.$refs.rainbow) {
        return;
      }

      if (this.$refs.stacks && !this.$refs.stacks?.classList.contains('visible')) {
        return;
      }

      const stacks = this.$refs.stacks;
      const container = this.$refs.rainbow;
      console.log(container.getBoundingClientRect());
      stacks.style.transform = `translateY(-${(container.getBoundingClientRect().top) / 2}px)`;

      const y = stacks.style.transform;
      if (y.includes('260')) {
        // stacks.style.transform = 'translateY(170px)';
        container.style.backgroundColor = stacks.children[0].attributes[0].value;
      } else if (y.includes('170')) {
        // stacks.style.transform = 'translateY(90px)';
        container.style.backgroundColor = stacks.children[1].attributes[0].value;
      } else if (y.includes('90')) {
        // stacks.style.transform = 'translateY(10px)';
        container.style.backgroundColor = stacks.children[2].attributes[0].value;
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

I have tried to make a normal CSS (without js) version of it on the Codepen. Please check this also out if it is of some help - https://codepen.io/yashwp5/pen/rNmvLRO

I'm struggling to make this work for the last 2 days :(.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic idea of how to do it in pure CSS. To add parallax scrolling for left-hand text, you'll have to use JS.

```css
.row-filler {
  height: 25vh;
}

.row-main {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50vh 0;
  background-color: #f7d3d8;
  color: #e57d61;
}
.static {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50vh;
}
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-filler"></div>

<div class="row-main">
    <div class="static">
      <div class="static-row-first">Create</div>
      <div class="static-row-last">yourDollar $</div>
    </div>

    <ul class="list">
        <li>ign</li>
        <li>NickelsBack</li>
        <li>ThereWillBeBud</li>
        <li>Rye&Reynolds</li>
        <li>My2Cents</li>
        <li>The6ixCents</li>
        <li>KillsBills</li>
        <li>Million$Baby</li>
        <li>ChequeMate</li>
        <li>SpendrickLamar</li>
        <li>hawnSpendez</li>
        <li>ign</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="row-filler"></div>
```

Comment: Hey @keymasterr I tried this solution but not helping. Also, I don't want to scroll the left side of the section as a parallax effect. Please let me know if you some other idea to it.

Comment: Can you please specify what's not working for you?

Comment: The sticky part is not working for me. I have tried to make the left container sticky. But it is not working.

Comment: Is the position of your sticky block set? The `top` property is an important part here

Comment: yes, I did set as `position: sticky; top: 100px` as navbar takes around 100px; But block/section is still scrolling

Comment: I can't guess what's the difference between your code and the one from my answer so I just modified your codepen: https://codepen.io/keymasterr/pen/YzVLNOx

The only changes are `position: relative;` for `.suggestion-container` and `position: sticky; top: 250px;` for `.suggestion-container .suggestion-label`

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same thing. But for some reason it is just not working!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235441/discussion-between-yashwardhan-pauranik-and-keymasterr).